# php if statement - time/date/strtotime related

Tags: php

I am using the following code to calculate the days remaining to make edits. They have 30 days  to make edits, and days count down, this code works perfectly.

```
 <?php       
 // Calculate days remains to edit or change details
 $today = time();
 $cdate = strtotime($row_details['payment_date']);//strtotime("19:19:09 Sep 27, 2011");
 $dateDiff = $today - $cdate;
 $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
 $dayscalculate = 30 - $fullDays; // Set number of days
 echo  $dayscalculate.(($dayscalculate == 1) ? " day" : " days");
 //
 ?>
```

QUESTION: if days = say 3 will say 3 days.. but if days = 0 (is the last of the 30 days).. Then want to say this is your last day or something.. So need an if based on $dayscalculate..

Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
if ($dayscalculate == 0) {
    echo 'This is your last day';
} else {
    printf('%d day%s',
        $dayscalculate,
        $dayscalculate > 1 ? 's' : ''
        );
}
```

You may also want to introduce an "out of time" check, ie `$dayscalculate < 0` but then again, you may already be handling this scenario.

Comment: @user718359 You do realise you practically wrote this yourself in pseudo-code, right?